# How do you fix "Property ' ' does not exist on type 'typeof import" error?

Tags: angular, import, auth0, webauthn

Aungluar newbie working on authentication. I downloaded the auth0-angular package to my project, and now I'm getting this error for my WebAuth() instance creation (IDE: VS Code):

" Property 'WebAuth' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/Users/Owner/Desktop/coding_course_docs/AngularAudioPlayer/node_modules/@auth0/auth0-angular/auth0-auth0-angular")' "

Here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as auth0 from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';



import{

  Observable,
  BehaviorSubject,
  bindNodeCallback, 
  of
} from 'rxjs';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  //instance of auth0-WebAuth that is used for authentication
  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({

    clientID: environment.auth0.clientID,

    domain: environment.auth0.domain,

    responseType: 'token id_token',

    scope: 'openid profile email'

  });

  //'localStorage' keys (for storing authentication and user profile data) that track whether or not to renew token
  private _authFlag = 'isLoggedIn';
  
  private _userProfileFlag = 'userProfile';
```

Any ideas of what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use another import for auth0?
`import * as auth0 from "auth0-js";`

Please note that the following dependency is required to use it: `auth0-js`, not `@types/auth0-js` (which should be added as well but it's just addition so you get better types in TypeScript for auth0)

If you want to use `auth0-angular`, then you should switch to another import type: `import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';`. You can find more details on usage of this AuthService here: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-angular-spa

While the first one should fix your issue, the second one is probably better way to go in the long run.

Comment: I tried `import * as auth0 from "auth0-js";` before this, and the CLI kept giving me an error, I actually posted for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69601214/what-does-cant-resolve-auth0-js-cli-error-mean-and-how-do-you-fix-it/69607866#69607866)

Comment: Also, should I try to import AuthService to this component or app.module?

Comment: Have you installed `auth0-js` package from NPM? By looking at your package.json you posted in this another question you mentioned I can only see `@types/auth0-js` but this package contains only type definitions for TypeScript, not auth0 itself. Try to add `auth0-js` dependency in your package.json and run `npm install` and check if it helps (and use this import `import * as auth0 from "auth0-js";` with this package)

Comment: Regarding AuthService - use this only you if you decided that you want to use this one instead of `auth0-js`. In this way check link I provided above, there is an example for this with explanations. Basically you need to import module and configure it in app.module (using AuthModule.forRoot) and then inject it in component's constructor and use injected instance.

Comment: Wooooow that worked! thanks so much! I didn't realize there was a difference between `auth0-js` and `@types/auth0-js`. Please forgive my newbieness! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help you :) You can also mark the my answer as accepted one if you want ;)